# Why does QTableWidget has a different behaviour when editing a column-span by double click or by "F2"-key

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

The table does have several column-spans. At "creation" i set the item (at the starting column of the span) to a from QTableWidgetItem derived one. If I edit the column-span by double-clicking the item i get from the itemChanged(..) signal is the item i set before. As it should be. However, if I edit by pressing the F2-key I'll get a different standard QTableWidgetItem handed over by the signal. Another fact is, that after i edited by double-click, editing by F2-key afterwards works as expected. I really don't understand this behavior. I hope some of you guys have an idea, and I hope you understand my description of the problem :).

Thx a lot
michael